# I want to pass collection variable to apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, invocable-method, getcontentaspdf

I want to pass the collection variable from flow to Apex which generates the PDF so, in collection variable, there are multiple records  ,that I want to show in visual force page

```
    @InvocableMethod()
    Global static void pdfGeneratorTrialInitiation(List<ID> trialId) {
 System.debug('trialId >>>>>>>>> '+trialId);
        List<Trial_Initiation_And_Monitoring__c> trial = [Select Id,Action_Taken_Date__c,Additive_Addition__c,After_Top_Up_Concentration__c,After_Top_Up_Date__c,After_Trial_Image__c,Before_Top_Up_Concentration__c,Before_Top_Up_Date__c,Before_Trial_Image__c,Charge_Date__c,Cleaner_Added_Ltr__c,Cleaner_Filtration__c,Cleaner_Monitoring_Date__c,Cleaner_Monitoring_Month__c,Component__c,
                                                          Contact_Number__c,Coolant__c,Customer_Name__c,Customer_Representative_Name__c,Customer_Singnature__c,Date_of_Trial__c,Department__c,End_Date__c,Job_Quantity__c,Machine_Number__c,Material__c,Name,Oil_Added__c,Opportunity__c,PH_Date__c,PH_Value__c,Product_Name__c,Recomented_TDS_Value__c,Recommended_Concentration_Max__c,Recommended_Concentration_Min__c,Recommended_pH_value__c,
                                                          Recommended_pH_value_Max__c,RecordTypeId,Remark__c,Select_Quarter__c,Select_Week__c,Start_Date__c,Tank_Cleaning__c,Tank_Cleaning_Date__c,Tank_Size__c,TDS__c,Tramp_Oil_Removal__c,Trial_Conduct_By__c,Water_Added_Ltr__c 
                                                          FROM Trial_Initiation_And_Monitoring__c
                                                          WHERE Id IN :trialId];
        
        System.debug('trial >>>>>>>>> '+trial);
        
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :trial[0].Opportunity__c];
        
        System.debug('opp >>>>>>>>> '+opp);
        
        /*-------------------- Save in File ------------------------- */
        
        PageReference pdf = Page.generatePDFPage;
        pdf.getParameters().put('Id', opp.Id);
        Blob pdfBlob;
        
        if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
            pdfBlob = blob.valueOf('Unit.Test');
        } else {
            pdfBlob = pdf.getContentAsPDF();
        }
        
    
        
        // Create a new ContentVersion record and insert it
        ContentVersion cont = new ContentVersion();
        cont.Title = opp.Name + 'genratePDFPage.pdf';
        cont.PathOnClient = 'file.pdf';
        cont.VersionData = pdfBlob;
        cont.Origin = 'C';
        insert cont;
        
        // Create a new ContentDocumentLink record and insert it
        ContentVersion contentVersion_2 = [SELECT Id, Title, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion
                                           WHERE Id = :cont.Id LIMIT 1];
        ContentDocumentLink contentlink = new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentlink.LinkedEntityId = opp.Id;
        contentlink.contentdocumentid = contentVersion_2.contentdocumentid;
        contentlink.ShareType = 'V';
        insert contentlink; 
    }
```

[image: this is the collection varibel]

When i am adding it as Input parm in apex action ,the variable is not showing there

[image]

Comment: Do you want LIST<ID> as parameter to the apex class?

Comment: yes I am passing the list of Id, which has to be from flow  
@SaiPraveenKakkirala

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass collection variable to  apex class then you have to define `List<List<id>>` in your apex class as parameter for that method.

If you want to pass just a single record or single Id then the apex method should have parameter as `List<Id>`

Please find [article](https://unhandledsunshine.com/2021/08/12/invocable-methods-how-to-send-data-between-flow-and-apex/) for the details on it

Answer (score 1):

Invocable Apex is always implicitly bulkified

Each element in the request corresponds to one Flow Interview

Thus

```
void pdfGeneratorTrialInitiation(List<ID> trialId)
```

means that `trialId[0]` corresponds to the first Flow Interview of the transaction.

*Invocable Apex doesn't know if it is being called from a Screen Flow or a record-triggered flow.*

- The former is the only Flow Interview in the transaction which is why you were lulled into thinking that `List<Id> trialId` was the collection variable in your screen flow
- But in a record-triggered flow, there could be 200 Flow Interviews in the transaction and `trialId[6]` would be the 7th Flow Interview of the transaction

To pass a collection of `trialIds` from a single Flow Interview, given that an invocable Apex can be used for record-triggered flows (or scheduled flows) as well as screen flows

```
void pdfGeneratorTrialInitiation(List<List<ID>> trialIds)
```

**Notes**

1. Collections should always be named with plurals. A better variableName that makes it clear what is happening with invocable Apex would be

   ```
   void pdfGeneratorTrialInitiation(List<List<ID>> trialIdsWithinInterviews)
   ```

or maybe

```
    void pdfGeneratorTrialInitiation(List<List<ID>> trialIdsWithinRequests)
```

1. Even if you think this invocable is only used for screen flows, at a minimum you should document that it is not bulkified and you should throw an exception if `trialIdsWithinInterviews.size() > 1`
2. Better, of course, and my practice, is to always bulkify invocables so they become reusable artifacts for record-triggered or scheduled flows